# How to combine two panel FIlters and Search Results?

Tags: filter, search-results, maps, faceted-search

I'm trying to combine two panels on the same page (map) - Filters and Search Results. The most obvious way to use tabs but I'm not sure that it's a good idea. What do you think?
[image: Filters]
[image: Search Results]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the method followed by Youtube and most other websites. Check this image. 
[image: Tucked away]

As you see, this way filters are tucked away. This is good if your users use search more than filters.

If the filters are used a lot, then you can follow the method used by real estate websites. Check this image.
[image: Combined with search]

This method requires that your users do use the filters a lot.

If you are unsure about the usage of filters, then it is best to follow the old school method. Check this image.

[image: Old style]

Answer (score 0):

The layout is ok. You just need to make sure that on final design the boundaries and white spaces between elements are given emphasis that will make the distinction and action is sensible. Google maps is also using similar approach.

[image]